# statistical differences between time series

Tags: time-series

I have 2 timeseries representing the energy expenditure of 2 group of patients.
Data are sampled every hour. The resulting plots represent indeed the hourly pattern of the EE of the 2 groups.

Is there a statistical test in order to compare (and emphatize differences) between 2 hourly patterns?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of differences are of interest?

Comment: @Silverfish I created a more detailed question... please have a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179947/statistical-differences-between-two-hourly-patterns I can't close this one...

Answer (score 0):

Coherence will indicate whether two series have the same frequencies. Phase shift will show what is the phase shift at these frequencies.

Comment: Would it work if I have only 24 data points (one each hour).

Comment: It depends on the pattern. It will certainly not work for any kind of pattern repeating daily or monthly. You can only detect frequencies between once in half hour and once a day.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question?
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179947/statistical-differences-between-two-hourly-patterns I asked to close the current one since it is very unclear...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Hodrick-Prescott filter to detect trends and cycles (daily or weekly) and compare among the two data series.

Comment: He has just one day data, 24 hourly observations.

Comment: Well, in this case one could just make H0: the two have same mean and apply a t-test. Better ideas?